# Why `SpringBootApplication` does not scan `Entites` and `Repositories` when custom jpa `@Configuration`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In my `library` I have some `Entities` and `Repositories` which I want include in my spring-boot project.

This is an example of `@Confituration` class from `library`

```kotlin
package com.mylibrary.config

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mylibrary.service")
@EntityScan("com.mylibrary.repo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mylibrary.repo")
@ConditionalOnClass(value = [DataSource::class])
open class MyCustomConfigFromLibrary
```

This way I try include `MyCustomConfigFromLibrary` in my spring-boot project

```kotlin
package com.mainapp

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = [MyCustomConfigFromLibrary::class])
class Application
```

But when I run my spring-boot application it does not want scan `Repositories` and `Entities` from my spring-boot project itself. It scans its `Components` but not its `Repositories` and `Entities`. `Repositories` and `Entities` it scans are only from my `library`.

So, to fix it I found the solution which I `do not` like! I just explicitly add `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` to my `Application` class.

```kotlin
package com.mainapp

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = [MyCustomConfigFromLibrary::class])
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
class Application
```

Comment: You can try to add spring auto-configuration to your library and then add it to your project as spring starter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you are using your own custom ***schema.sql and/or data.sql*** then Spring Boot does not detect JPA Repos or Entities. If you want your application to scan those classes then try removing the custom **schema.sql/data.sql** from the *resources* folder.

In the JPA based app, You should not use both ***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto*** and ***schema.sql***. Make sure to disable ***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto*** if you use ***schema.sql***.

Reference - https://walkingtechie.blogspot.com/2018/12/execute-schema-and-data-sql-on-startup-spring-boot.html